# Table view using CollectionView

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview

I have to represent data in a table.
I'm trying to build a layout suited to do this.

I was thinking something like:

I have already started with the implementation.
I have built a programmatically Collecionview and this is the result:

![MyWork][2]

On the internet there are infinite solutions. To me this seemed the most suitable but now I have two main problems:

- I have implemented the CollectionView horizontally. So if I put
  more than 15 ithem structure comes out badly because it adds the
  ithem in a new column. So I wish it adds below and create a vertical
  scroll view
- second problem is to block the first column from the first line and
  horizontal scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Use rotated table view

```
-(void) didLoad{
 ....
[self.tableView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/-2);
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
....
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

SEScrollMenuCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"menuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//use custom UI objects inside cell
cell.label_text.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.label_text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
cell.label_text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

cell.label_text.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
cell.label_text.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 32.0, [[self.items_width objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] doubleValue]);
.......
return cell;
}
```